# Android limit length to width of the EditText

Tags: android, ios, android-edittext, uitextfield

I'm looking for a way to limit the length of the text (similar to maxLength but dynamically) based on the width of the `EditText`.

An example is that an `EditText` of length 600px (at dpi 3.5) can have maximum of 10 `m` but 14 `i`.

An answer for `UITextField` in iOS is also very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                Rect bounds = new Rect();
                Paint textPaint = editText.getPaint();
                textPaint.getTextBounds(editText.getText().toString(), 0, editText.getText().toString().length(), bounds);
                int width = bounds.width();
                if (width > max_width) {
                    editText.setText(editText.getText().toString().substring(0, editText.getText().toString().length() - 1));
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: I have done almost the same thing with `editText.measuredWidth` but and `paint.measureText()` but there seems to be some padding added...

Comment: Please follow the above solution exactly and let me know if it works for you

Comment: I can confirm that the width from `.getTextBounds()` is correct, the thing is the variable `max_width` in your example need to be calculated as well. I'm using `measuredWidth` but it seems changing.

Comment: calculated based on what?

Comment: No, it was set to match parent (`0dp` in `AutoLayout`). For some reasons `editText.measureWidth` is not working (changing) but `editText.measure(0, 0)` then `editText.width` return the correct value. I just have to add `2dp` as some padding then the calculation is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of Antonis is correct, I just want to share the complete version:

```
val dpi = context.resources.displayMetrics.density
RxTextView.afterTextChangeEvents(editText)
        .debounce(300L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .map { it.editable().toString() }
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe {
            editText.measure(0, 0)
            val width = editText.width - 4 * dpi
            val textWidth = editText.paint.measureText(it)
            if (width > textWidth) {
                // get the data
            } else {
                editText.setText(it.dropLast(1))
                editText.setSelection(if (it.length > 1) it.length - 1 else 0)
            }
        }
        .addTo(composite)
```

Comment: I believe that editText.measure(0, 0)  is not need. Glad it's working :)

Comment: Thanks, I have to call it inside `afterTextChanged` otherwise I get `0` for `width`